# Solving biased eigendecomposition problem, $\mathbf{AV_B}=\mathbf{V_B\Lambda_B} + \mathbf{Y_B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ with $\mathbf{\Lambda_B}\in\mathbb{R}^{B\times B}$ as the diagonal matrix containing $B\ (B\ll N)$ eigenvalues of matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Is there any iterative algorithm that could obtain $\mathbf{V_B}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times B}$ that satisfies the following equation,
$$
\mathbf{AV_B} =\mathbf{V_B \Lambda_B} + \mathbf{Y_B},
$$
given the bias matrix $\mathbf{Y_B}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times B}$?

The reason I'm looking for an iterative algorithm is that the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ cannot be stored explicitly, but we can calculate the matrix-vector multiplication, $\mathbf{Av}$.

Edit (additional note): The each column of $\mathbf{Y_B}$ is guaranteed to be perpendicular to the corresponding eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Note that solving this for $B=1$ is enough, since this can be decomposed into $B$ distinct equations. So, you only need to solve for $(A-\lambda_1 I)v_1=y_1$. Since $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, this matrix is singular, so an exact solution might not exist. However you can find "closest" solutions with pseudo-inverse for example. Unfortunately, I don't know any way to calculate pseudo-inverse only using matrix-vector multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added an additional note in the post saying that each column in $\mathbf{Y_B}$ is perpendicular to the corresponding eigenvectors. So the value of $\mathbf{v_i}$ that satisfies $(\mathbf{A} - \lambda_i \mathbf{I})\mathbf{v_i} = \mathbf{y_i}$ can actually be found. They just might not be unique.